# Can I customize a color with a name in MaterialTheme in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Before I define a color with a name in resources file such as Code A, and access it using such as  `Divider(color = colorResource(R.color.colorGrey))`.

Now I read the [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources). I get the following warning:

*Prefer colors from the theme rather than hard-coded colors. Even though it's possible to access colors using the colorResource function, it's recommended that the colors of your app are defined in a MaterialTheme which can be accessed from your composables like MaterialTheme.colors.primary.*

So I study Code B, I find I can use such as `MaterialTheme.colors.secondary` to access a color.

I find there are only some preset colors with name in colors such as `primary`, `primaryVariant`, ...etc, it seems that I can only overwrite preset colors such as `primary = Purple900`.

I hope I can customize a color with a name in `MaterialTheme,` so I can use such as `MaterialTheme.colors.myIcon` to access color, how can I do?

**Code A**

```
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="colorGrey">#FF6200EE</color>
</resources>
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun SoundMeterTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}


private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors(
    primary = Purple200,
    primaryVariant = Purple700,
    secondary = Teal200
)

fun darkColors(
    primary: Color = Color(0xFFBB86FC),
    ...
): Colors = Colors(
    primary,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply just want a named color, just a global static will work for you. There is no need to use `MaterialTheme`.

Just have a `Color.kt` file with top level public constant declarations.

```
val MyGrey = Color(#FF6200EE)
```

or you could sort of namespace them with

```
object MyColors {
   val Grey = Color(#FF6200EE)
}
```

Then you can just use it in your composables

```
Divider(color = MyColors.Grey)
```

---

The downside though is that now you are not supporting dark theme or other possible config changes. For that you can extend `MaterialTheme` and we have docs on how to do that [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes/custom#extending-material)

For your example of `myIcon` it would be

```
import androidx.compose.material.Colors

val Colors.myIcon: Color
    get() = if (isLight) Color(#...) else Color(#...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use compositionLocal to feed data into your composable.

simple example:

```
private val LocalMyColors = compositionLocalOf {
    DarkColorPalette
}

@Stable
object MyTheme {
    val colors: darkColors
        @Composable
        get() = LocalMyColors.current

    enum class Theme {
        Light, Dark
    }
}
@Composable
fun SoundMeterTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalMyColors  provides colors) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colors = colors,
            typography = Typography,
            shapes = Shapes,
            content = content
        )
    }
}

fun darkColors(
    primary: Color = Color(0xFFBB86FC),
    ...
): Colors = Colors(
    primary,
    ...
)
```

use:

```
LocalMyColors.current.primary
MyTheme.colors.primary
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I access color using such as `MaterialTheme.colors.myIcon` by your way?

Comment: No, MaterialTheme.color can not be modified, You can Customize the theme and then add myIcon

Comment: You can extend MaterialTheme.color, see my answer